# Gathering data with the same ID from across multiple rows into one row by adding columns

Tags: r, merge, row, multiple-columns

I am learning to use R/Rstudio on a Windows machine and have not found a solution to my problem.
I have a dataframe with thousands of observations and 10 columns (numeric, factors and dates).
IDs in my first column often occur many times in different rows.

I would like to get all values of all the rows with the same ID into one row.

I have tried loops, across, merge, gather, spread, etc. but  I have not yet found a way.

Here is a made-up example of the data I have:

```
id<-rep(c(1,2,3,4),times=5)
df1<-data.frame(id)
df1$type <- rep(c(22, 50, 49, 33), times = 5) 
df1$begin <- rep(c(2020-05-23, 2020-06-24, 2020-04-18, 2020-09-07), times = 5) 
df1$end <- rep(c(2021-07-23, 2021-04-24, 2021-03-18, 2021-10-07), times = 5)
```

`df1`

|  | id | type | begin | end |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 22 | 1992 | 1991 |
| 2 | 2 | 50 | 1990 | 1993 |
| 3 | 3 | 49 | 1998 | 2000 |
| 4 | 4 | 33 | 2004 | 2004 |
| 5 | 1 | 22 | 1992 | 1991 |
| 6 | 2 | 50 | 1990 | 1993 |
| 7 | 3 | 49 | 1998 | 2000 |
| 8 | 4 | 33 | 2004 | 2004 |
| 9 | 1 | 22 | 1992 | 1991 |
| 10 | 2 | 50 | 1990 | 1993 |
| 11 | 3 | 49 | 1998 | 2000 |
| 12 | 4 | 33 | 2004 | 2004 |
| 13 | 1 | 22 | 1992 | 1991 |
| 14 | 2 | 50 | 1990 | 1993 |
| 15 | 3 | 49 | 1998 | 2000 |
| 16 | 4 | 33 | 2004 | 2004 |
| 17 | 1 | 22 | 1992 | 1991 |
| 18 | 2 | 50 | 1990 | 1993 |
| 19 | 3 | 49 | 1998 | 2000 |
| 20 | 4 | 33 | 2004 | 2004 |

My end result should look something like this:

| id | type | begin | end | tpye2 | begin2 | end2 | type3 | begin3 | end3 | etc. |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 22 | 1992 | 1991 | 22 | 1991 | 1992 | 1 | 22 | 1992 |  |
| 2 | 50 | 1990 | 1993 | 50 | 1990 | 1993 | 50 | 1990 | 1993 |  |

I hope this makes sense. Any help is greatly appreciated.
Many thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

Try pivot_wider, Lmk.

```
df1 %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(V = row_number()) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  pivot_wider(
    id_cols = id,
    names_from = V,
    values_from =  !c(id, V),
    values_fill = NA)
```

Comment: Great answer. If you change the values_from argument to values_from = !c(id, V), you can avoid the need for the last select statement

Comment: Great, i was wondering about that ugly select haha. Just edited the answer. Thanks